# how can I use - in a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a little calculator with HTML and JavaScript. I ran in to a problem that I can't solve and that is using minus in a JavaScript function.

The function:

```
function min() {
    var getal1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;
    var getal2 = document.getElementById("n2").value;
    var result = parseInt(getal1) - parseInt(getal2);
    document.getElementById("uitkomst").value = result;
}
```

can someone help?
Here is a working snippet:

```js
function min() {
    var getal1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;
    var getal2 = document.getElementById("n2").value;
    var result = parseInt(getal1) - parseInt(getal2);
    document.getElementById("uitkomst").value = result;
}
```

```html
Number 1: <input type="number" id="n1"><br>
Number 2: <input type="number" id="n2"><br>

<input type="submit" value="min" onclick="min()"><br>

Result <input type="number" id="result">
```

Comment: What happened when you tried the code that you posted?

Comment: *"I ran in to a problem that i can't solve"* -- what is the problem?

Comment: Please go read [ask], and [mcve].

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Comment: Please add a working snippet!!

Comment: @axiac the problem is that this does not work

Comment: The function as is *does work*. However the ids might be wrong or `min()` is called at a wrong time (before the page is loaded)

Comment: And by the way welcome to SO, we are glad to help you :)

Comment: "this does not work" is not a useful statement. Tell us _exactly_ what it does and why that confuses you. Also, provide enough code for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @JosephSible i ran the program evrything worked fine accept for that block of code there

Comment: *"It does not work"* doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Use developers tools in your browser and check if there is some error in the console.

Comment: @Slai i'll just have to change the name then

Answer (score 3):

It's because `min` is an `input` attribute, so `onclick="min()"` points to the attribute i.e. `this.min` instead of the function in outer scope.

```html
<p><input type="submit" value="min" onclick="console.log(min)" min="123"></p>
```

As suggested in the comments([@Ivar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479156/ivar)), the way to workaround this would be to use `window.min` to specify global scope.

`<p><input type="submit" value="min" onclick="window.min()"></p>`

Or switch to using `button` element.

`<button onclick="min()">min</button>`